# Methods To Create a 3-Column Layout: Fluid - Fixed - Fluid

Tags: html, css

How can we create a 3-column layout, Fluid - Fixed - Fluid, as shown in the picture below. Is there more than one option? If so, what are the pros and cons of each?

**Note**: Feel free to add more answers if they are different to the three I've already posted. Also, I know this has been asked before, but I can't find anywhere with all three answers that is up to date.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Options

There are  <s>three</s>  **four** ways of doing this, all using different CSS and having different levels of complexity and browser compatibility. In all  <s>three</s>  **four**, we start with three `div`s which create our three columns.

**Method 1** - Most compatible, longest code.

**Method 2** - Medium compatible, medium code.

**Method 3** - Least compatible, shortest code.

All  <s>three</s>  **four** will produce what we want, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

### EDIT:

There is a Method 4, suggested by `vals`, which uses the CSS `Flexbox` Model. See his answer for details.

---

## Method 1 - Extra Inner `div`

Insert an extra `div` inside the left and right fluid columns.

***Pros:*** This method has the best compatibility, even back to IE6.

***Cons:*** We have to insert an extra `div`, and the CSS is the longest of all three methods.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWsH2/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="fluid left">
        <div class="inner">
            Fluid Box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        Fixed Box
    </div>
    <div class="fluid right">
        <div class="inner">
            Fluid Box
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrap div {
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}
.fixed {
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:500px;
}
.fluid {
    background-color:orange;
    width:50%;
}
.left {
    margin-left:-250px;
}
.left .inner {
    margin-left:250px;
}
.right {
    margin-right:-250px;
}
.right .inner {
    margin-right:250px;
}
```

---

## Method 2 - Use `box-sizing` CSS Styling

If you are willing to use some CSS3, you can set the left and right fluid columns to have `box-sizing:border-box;`. This lets use take the `margin` from the Method 1's inner `div`s, and place it as padding in the outer `div`s, without interfering with their `width`s. `box-sizing` isn't supported by all older browsers though.

***Pros:*** The code is cleaner, because we don't have an extra inner `div`. The CSS is slightly cleaner as well.

***Cons:*** Browser compatibility. We are going to [**lose IE6 and IE7**](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWsH2/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="fluid left">
        Fluid Box
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        Fixed Box
    </div>
    <div class="fluid right">
        Fluid Box
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrap div {
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}
.fixed {
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:500px;
}
.fluid {
    background-color:orange;
    width:50%;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.left {
    margin-left:-250px;
    padding-left:250px;
}
.right {
    margin-right:-250px;
    padding-right:250px;
}
```

---

## Method 3 - Use `calc()` for `width`

Following the trend, we can use a method which involves even newer CSS, for even cleaner but less backward-compatible code. If we calculate the `width` of the left and right fluid columns using `width:calc(% - px)`, we don't need `box-sizing`, or extra `div`s.

***Pros:*** The CSS is even cleaner and shorter than in method 2.

***Cons:*** Browser compatibility. Not only do we lose older versions of IE, we lose all but the very [**newest versions of most mobile browsers.**](http://caniuse.com/calc).

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWsH2/3/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="fluid">
        Fluid Box
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        Fixed Box
    </div>
    <div class="fluid">
        Fluid Box
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.wrap div {
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}
.fixed {
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:500px;
}
.fluid {
    background-color:orange;
    width:-webkit-calc(50% - 250px);
    width:-moz-calc(50% - 250px);
    width:calc(50% - 250px);
}
```

---

## Summary

**Method 1** - Most compatible, longest code.

**Method 2** - Medium compatible, medium code.

**Method 3** - Least compatible, shortest code.

Comment: 1+ This is a nice canonical answer. Method 3 is really nice. You could also achieve this with CSS tables (i.e., `display:table`/`display:table-cell`.)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using those types of `display`, because I tend to shy away from anything with `tables`. I'll look into it though, and update my answer. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: And method 4, using flex model

Answer (score 2):

## Method 4 - Flex Model

Similar to Method 3 in AndyM's post, this method relies on CSS3 and will only work in modern browsers. However, as it's name would suggest, it's flexible, and easy to implement. We use three new CSS properties: `display:flex;` `flex-grow:;`, and `flex-basis:;`.

We add the first to `#wrap`, which tells the browser that the items inside are going to be laid out using the flex model. The second two tell the browser whether or not an item will grow (is flexible), and what is the initial width.

***Pros***: The CSS is clean and short, and very easy to change later. Unlike Method 2 & 3, the fixed width only needs to be declared once.

***Cons***: Browser compatibility. This has just slightly better compatibility than `calc()`, but not by much. We can use it now, but we [lose basically all but the newest versions of most mobile browsers, and of Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWsH2/4/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="fluid">
        Fluid Box
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
        Fixed Box
    </div>
    <div class="fluid">
        Fluid Box
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    height:300px;
} 
.fixed {
    background-color:lightblue;
    flex-grow: 0;  /* Does this box grow? 0 means no. */
    flex-basis: 500px;
} 
.fluid {
    background-color:orange;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0px;
}
```

I've edited this to make the example as close as possible to the examples in Methods 1-3, for easier comparison of the methods. All kudos to vals for the initial post, I had never heard of this method. - AndyM

[Original Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znUP7/)

Comment: Looks good! Only thing about this that worries me is that many older browsers use an older syntax that was changed. With current syntax, this has almost as limited compatibility as `calc()`. The code is beautifully simple though! Do you mind if I edit to change the HTML structure to match the 3 other examples, for ease of comparison?

Comment: Feel free to edit it in any way you like. And yes, flex makes things really easy. Just need to wait for a wider support ...

Comment: Some of the styles were lost because your edit was not accepted by the comunity. I rescued it from the log history, but I guess that there it keeps only the text without styles. Well, it's ok now.